# Change a boolean back and forth in Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, dom-events

I wonder if it is possible in Javascript to have a `click` event listener that every time I click changes my boolean from true to false back and forth. Meaning I click one it goes to false, I click again and it goes to true and so on in an infinite loop. I don't even know if it is possible but I tried this:

```
//This is my listener
circlePicker.click(function () {
    booleanChecker(circlePickerSelector);
    console.log(booleanChecker(circlePickerSelector));
});

//This function checks if the boolean is true or false
function booleanChecker(isThisTrue) {
    // circlePickerSelector = !circlePickerSelector;
    // return circlePickerSelector;
    if (isThisTrue == false) {
        isThisTrue = true;
        console.log("I turned into true");
    } else if (isThisTrue == true) {
        isThisTrue = false;
        console.log("I turned into false");
    }
    return isThisTrue;
}
```

I would like to know if this is possible. I get a feeling something is wrong in my syntax. Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can toggle it by using the `!` operator

```
circlePicker.click(function () {
    circlePickerSelector = !circlePickerSelector;
    console.log(circlePickerSelector);
});
```

If `circlePickerSelector` was originally `true`, then `!circlePickerSelector` turns it to `false`. You can then assign it to the same variable to do the reverse on next click.

Answer (score 4):

Create a closure around a variable then return a function from inside that closure, for example,

```
function bool(initial) {
    initial = !!initial;
    return {
         get current() {
             return initial;
         },
         toggle: function () {
             return initial = !initial;
         }
    };
}
var b = bool(true);
b.current;  // true
b.toggle(); // false
b.current;  // false
b.toggle(); // true
b.current;  // true
```